# Php translating REYES

Tags: php, translate

I have a database, first name, last name etc. I made a php file, so I could search for fragments of the first and last name.  E.g. if the full name was winston churchill, i could type in the first name field 'nst' ,  and in the last name field 'hill', and it will pull up the winston churchill record and any others that matched.

I did a search for this guy ariel reyes,  fname='ar'  lname='reyes'  and php changes all the 'reyes' to KINGS.

Google translate tells me REYES is Spanish for KINGS,

Oddly enough it causes the first name field to have extra spaces around the "AR" also.  How do you get php not to 'translate' anything?

Comment: Believe it or not, PHP doesn't have an automatic "translate everything to English" feature: if any translation is being done, it's as a result of your code, not something intrinsic to PHP... but as you haven't shown any of your own code, we can't help show what you've done wrong

Comment: I believe it's [magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fK17YdiQ78) //see manual pages